# How to uncheck a checkbox on unselection of a particular checkbox

Tags: jquery

I want to uncheck checkbox based on unselection of another check box.
ex.

```
    <input id=isActive_1 type=checkbox />
<input id=isActive_2 type=checkbox />
<input id=isActive_3 type=checkbox />


    <input id=publish_1 type=checkbox />
<input id=publish_2 type=checkbox />
<input id=publish_3 type=checkbox />
```

when i uncheck 'isActive_1' then 'publish_1' should be unchecked at this time.
Please help me out

Comment: if you select both isActive_1 and isActive_2 what will happen?

Answer (score 2):

See this:  [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vJvR8/)

```
$('input[id^=isActive_]').change(function () {
   $("input[id^=publish" + this.id.replace('isActive', '') + "]").attr('checked', this.checked);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("input#isActive_1").click(function(){
 if($('input#isActive_1:checked').length > 0)
   $('input#publish_1').attr('checked', true);
 else
   $('input#publish_1').attr('checked', false);
});
```

**Edit :** Wrong test to know if "isActive_1" checkbox is checked or not on first time.

Comment: Dude, `attr` is not the one to use!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input#isActive_1").click(function(){
        if(!$("input#isActive_1").prop("checked"))
          $("input#publish_1").prop("checked", false);
        else
          $("input#publish_1").prop("checked", true);
    });
});
```

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/praveenscience/uJxL8/

---

**Updated from comment**

Use regex selectors this way:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("[id^=isActive_]").click(function(){
        /////
    });
});
```

Comment: but i don't know which which isActive check box well be deselected . i want to get it dynamic. ie. if i have 20 isActive checkbox then i will not check manullay

Comment: @user1280492 Check the fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

First of all use double quotes for attribute values, and use the id of `isActive_` checkboxes to get the index of `publish_`

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kP5nm/1/)**

*Html*

```
<input id="isActive_1" type="checkbox" />
<input id="isActive_2" type="checkbox" />
<input id="isActive_3" type="checkbox" />
<input id="publish_1" type="checkbox" />
<input id="publish_2" type="checkbox" />
<input id="publish_3" type="checkbox" />
```

*Javascript*

```
$('[id^=isActive_]').change(function () {
    $('#publish_' + this.id.replace('isActive_', '')).attr('checked', this.checked);
});
```

Comment: This acts on checking and on unchecking. OP asked only for an unchecking action so have to suspect a test is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tXd8G/3/)

```
$(function() {
    $(document).on("click", "input[id^='isActive_']", function() {
        var number = +$(this).attr("id").substring(9);
        var checked = $(this).prop("checked");

        // for checking & unchecking behaviour
        //$("#publish_"+number).prop("checked", checked);

        if(!checked) {
            $("#publish_"+number).prop("checked", false);
        }
    });
});
```

(or with "change" event)

You can now add as many checkboxes as you like and even dynamically (e.g. after page is loaded & JavaScript executed - from AJAX)

Comment: This acts on checking and on unchecking. OP asked only for an unchecking action so have to suspect a test is necessary.